# why my computer does not detect GPU and using CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I have a Gforce 1080 Ti GPU and I installed visuall studio 2017 enterprise, 430.64-desktop-win10-64bit-international-whql, cuda_10.0.130_411.31_win10, cudnn-9.0-windows10-x64-v7.4.2.24 and Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64 respectively on my computer. after that, I make a virtual environment variable using Anaconda command prompt and install TensorFlow-GPU using this command: `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorFlow-gpu==1.9` but my system using CPU instead of gpu.one time at first it used gpu and then during learning my network, it used CPU again. what is the problem? and what should I do to solve this problem and make force my system to use GPU? please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_source_configurations

tensorflow_gpu-1.9.0 only supports CUDA 9.0, it might be the issue. I suggest you could try tensorflow_gpu-1.13.1